# Fail authentication using VBA to fill IE form

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, passwords

I have a problem to login on a website using IE.

My code(see at the end) fills the login/password fields without problem and then clicks on the submit button. But then I receive an error "Login failed" (without more details).

The weird part is that if I manually copy/paste the password then click on that damn button the login is successful.

I know that the website does not allow autofill functions (AutoComplete="OFF"in the HTML). Can it be related? Do you think there's a workaround?

Let me know if you need any information that could be helpful.

Thanks!
Paul

```
Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document.frames(1).Document
HTMLdoc.getElementById("txtUsername").Value = "XXXXX"
HTMLdoc.getElementById("txtPassword").Value = "YYYYY"
HTMLdoc.all("btnLogin").Click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! I guess the website is tracking the password completion to make sure it's a human who's' trying to log in. Anyway even if it's less clean it works with sendKeys:

```
' Login
Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document.frames(1).Document
HTMLdoc.getElementById("txtUsername").Select
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
SendKeys "5536SP01"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
HTMLdoc.getElementById("txtPassword").Select
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
SendKeys "Chartered123"
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
HTMLdoc.all("btnLogin").Click
```